# While I am using cucumber with Maven in eclipse, it is not recognizing @given,@when, @then

Tags: eclipse, maven, cucumber

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.test.cucumber</groupId>
  <artifactId>com.test.cucumber</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java8</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.52.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>21.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

  
</project>
```

While I am using cucumber with Maven in eclipse, it is not recognizing @given,@when, @then tags. The versions used are java1.8, eclipse oxygen,maven integration to eclipse 1.5 and cucumber eclipse plugin 0.23.

Gherkin syntax is getting recognized if am not using Maven and code is running well.I tried using same versions of dependencies in pom.xml file. But still it is not importing import cucumber.api.java.en.; and throwing error.
Below is the pom.xml file for reference.

Comment: please share your pom.xml cucumber dependencies its probably bcz you would have added direct and transitive dependencies together which is causing this outcome.

Answer (score 0):

However you have not shared pom.xml. but It happens when we mix direct & transitive dependencies. So **we shall not mix direct & transitive dependencies specially their versions! Doing so can cause unpredictable outcome.** Below are few errors being reported by people due to wrong use of dependencies.

- The import cucumber.api.junit cannot be resolved
- java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gherkin/IGherkinDialectProvider
- import cucumber.api.DataTable; cannot be resolved

**Solution:** You can add below set of minimal cucumber dependencies. In case you are using info.cukes dependencies, please start using io.cucumber dependencies as

- info.cuke is is pretty old dependency having last version as 1.2.5 and no support is being provided after September 2016 and
- io.cucumber is the latest one having version from 2 - 4.3 where we can see all the latest updates from Cucumber team

  ```
  <dependency>
  <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
  <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
  <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
  <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  ```

Comment: thanks...changing the dependency to io.cucumber worked for me well.

Comment: Can you please accept the answer and vote it as it would be meaning for others as well when they face same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this in my POM.XML and it's works:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <groupId>groupId</groupId>
        <artifactId>CucumberBasic</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.3</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.3</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.12</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>

    </project>
```